# Does Integration of DataDriven Test framework with kibana make sense?

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver, automated-tests, cucumber, kibana

I have a dilemma. I have a Cucumber-Java framework integrated with Jenkins. It is primarily sequential testing with a lot of different inputs. As an output, I have Extent Reports from Cucumber, and I'm also running multiple jobs with different test sets (tags). Please tell me your honest opinion about whether it makes any sense to integrate it together with Kibana/Grafana. Is it really that beneficial, considering that it can provide historical trend analysis? Will this approach be meaningful in this case?

Comment: It's pretty useful if you want to figure out which tests get slower over time. Flake analysis is possible too if you're doing scheduled runs.

Comment: That depends. I capture logs for every test run and save that file into cloud and writes the files location respective to date and time in data base. In my case, I can go and check any old logs. If you want a tool to track all logs together then you can go for it.